# What's the image upload flow for websites with CDN

Tags: file-upload, cdn, azure-cdn, system-design

I'm preparing for system design interviews and can't seem to find an answer to the question below -

*What happens when a user uploads an image to Facebook (or any other platform that uses CDN, such as Twitter, WhatsApp, or other social media platforms)?*

Let's assume

- Facebook's **origin server** is in California, US
- user_a is in India.

This user must be connected to a CDN network **edge server**, which is providing all serving requests to this user on behalf of Facebook's origin server.

What occurs when user a uploads an image?  -

1. Will the upload request be sent to the core server, where it will be propagated to the CDN network, and the CDN URL will be returned to user_a to be cached in the user_a's browser?
2. Upload will take place at the CDN edge server, and the user will be given the cdn url (which user_a's browser can cache), and CDN can submit this image to FB's core server.

Comment: How is the CDN involved here? I don't think they should provide read capabilities for everybody